# Searching an element with specific text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get an element that contains specific text. When I use the :contains selector, the result is also all of the parents elements of that specific element.

Also, if there is more than on element that actually contains the text, the result of the selector is very cumbersome. Is it possible to get only the elements themselves which contains the specific text?

Thanks,
Joel

EDIT:

Example:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and $("div:contains('text')") results in:

```
[<div>​…​</div>​, <div>​…​</div>​, <div>​text​</div>​]
```

I want a way to only get the `<div>text</div>` element. (I know I can use .get(-1) to get that last element, but I want to know if there is something more gemeric).

Comment: Can you post your html as well as an example of what elements you want to get versus what you do not want to get?

Comment: hi , i did not understand you, what do  you mean about "Text" ? you mean InnerText? or InnerHTML?

Comment: Sorry, added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$(":contains('text')").each(function() {
  if($(this).find(":contains('text')").length > 0) {
    // ignore. this is just an element containing at least 1 child containing 'text'
  }
  else {
    // this is an element you want, directly contains 'text'
    // .. your code here ..
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not khow this way work right , but you check it , if it was not work, comment me to edit it for an other solution

```
$("div[innerHTML=text]")
```